# Repeat each line multiple times by using Linux

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-18.04

I have 1 file with some data. Like

my_file:

```
1 3 a
4 8 b
9 14 c
```

output_file:

```
a
a
b
b
b
b
c
c
c
c
c
```

I am trying to repeat each line multiple times(3-1 = 2 , 8-4 =4 , 14-9 = 5). I am tying this command:

```
while read i; do seq 1 2| xargs -i -- echo $i;done < my_file.txt
```

But it is repeating 2 times for all lines. I want to repeat each line N times. Is it possible? If it is will you please give me some suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `seq 1 $n` instead of `seq 1 2`

Comment: It is showing as same as my input file.

Comment: I don't see the logic. Why is N=3 for `a`, N=2 for `b`, N=4 for `c`, etc?

Comment: Because I have some preconditions. For "a" if the precondition value(N) is 3, then I have to print 3 times that line.  For "b" if the precondition value(N) is 4, then I have to print 4 times that line.

Comment: And where do those preconditions come from. If you want to automate it, there has to be a rule to follow.

Comment: my_file.txt
1 4 a
5 9 b
10 20 c
So I have to calculate the difference and have to print "a" "b" "c" that many times. That is the main reason.

Comment: Why isn't that in the question?

Comment: Please update the question to show the correct contents of `my_file.txt`, and the corresponding output. Because that input should have 10 `c`, not just 3.

Comment: Is `1 4 a` one line or 3 lines?

Comment: @jonson Please edit your question and include the `my_file.txt 1 4 a 5 9 b 10 20 c` "thing" (file content?) inside your question. Please explain how that "precondition value(N)" works.

Comment: Yes in one line. Ok Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I am bash shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) is an option:

```
perl -ne '@A=split;print "$A[2]\n" x ($A[1]-$A[0])' my_file.txt
```

For each line, it `split`s the line on whitespace and `@A` is the array holding that result.

It then prints the third element in the array (`$A[2]`) + a newline, repeated (the `x`) the number of times you have if you take the value in column 2 minus the value in column 1.

Answer (score 2):

Read each line into 3 variables, and use the first two variables as the range for the repetitions.

```
while read -r start end char; do
    for ((i = start; i < end; i++)); do
        echo "$char"
    done
done < my_file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Using awk for it:

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=$2-$1;i++)print $3}' file
```

Output:

```
a
a
b
b
b
b
c
c
c
c
c
```

Comment: `n` is different for each line.

Comment: Check out his comment. He says the number of repetitions comes from the file, not hard-coded like that.